# Could u give me an example how to read "#"-parameters from GET request in ASP.NET web api?

Tags: asp.net-web-api

http://localhost/#access_token=94719dfb&expires_in=86400&...
Is there any example where controller read parameters from "#" type values?

Comment: Maybe I have never seen it but to my knowledge, there is no such thing as a '#' type in the query string

Comment: @JasonH a hashtag (`#`) in a URL is called a fragment identifier.

Comment: @Nkosi Sorry I should have been more specific in my comment, I have never seen the use of a # in an API Call, I have seen them with website calls.  I have learned something new though as I did not know you could use them with APIs

Answer (score 0):

Extract the URL fragment from the request. From there you can parse the fragment and extract the desired  values

```cs
public class TestController : ApiController {
    public IHttpActionResult Get() {
        var url = Request.RequestUri;

        var fragment = url.Fragment; //eg: #access_token=94719dfb&expires_in=86400&

        //...parse the fragment and extract what you needs

        return Ok(fragment);
    }
}
```

> [Uri.Fragment Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.fragment(v=vs.110).aspx)
>
> The Fragment property gets any text following a fragment marker (#) in
>   the URI, including the fragment marker itself. Given the URI
>   `http://www.contoso.com/index.htm#main`, the `Fragment` property would
>   return `#main`.